# Force JQuery $.each() run once if array of objects is 1 in length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using $.each it iterate over an argumented array of objects. It works fine until the array only has 1 object in it and the $.each iterates over it's properties. In this scenario I want the loop to run once only. How do I achieve this?

```js
$.each(array, function() {
  // Do stuff with each object in the array
})
```

Edit: The array is comprised of JSON objects returned from an AJAX call. Most of the time this will be multiple objects but it could only be 1.

```js
$.post("/receive", JSON.stringify(postData), function(data) {
  // calling the above function and argumenting data.
}, "json")
```

Comment: Create a sample array like the one you have been dealing with and post your code in a fiddle for us to be able to help with no wasting time assuming what your array would look like!

Comment: You mean that `array` can be an array of objects or it can be just an object itself?

Comment: So `data` is normally `[{}, {}, ...]` but it can be `{...}` sometimes?

Comment: Exactly, and then I want to run the loop once on that object instead of iterating over it.

Comment: @dfsq that is what I also understood from the vaguely asked question. IMO the solution is: fix the server-side script to always return an array.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOlivier In this case you want to wrap this single object into array. E.g. `data = data instanceof Array ? data : [data]`.

Comment: @CompuChip I'll definitely have to clean up the server side output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `data` can be an array of objects and sometimes an object itself without wrapping array you can still use `$.each` loop to handle both situations uniformly: just turn single object into array of one object and use `$.each` like you always use for array of multiple objects:

```
data = [].concat(data);
$.each(data, function() {
    // Do stuff with each object in the array
});
```

If `data` is an array then `[].concat` will produce new similar array, otherwise if `data` is an object you will get `[data]`.

Or you could also do it like this:

```
data = data instanceof Array ? data : [data];
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Apologies for the vague question. Going to glue my hair back in now.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
test = [{a:1, b:2}];
$.each(test, function(id, elem) { 
  console.log(elem);
});
```

Outputs the object as expected

```
Object {a: 1, b: 2}
```

If your ajax calls returns either an array or an object, test if the object is an array

```
Array.isArray(test) // == true
```